# Firebase: How do I retrieve records from my data for which a specific key exists?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have data in firebase that looks like this:

```
"application": {
  "companies": {
    "firebase": {
      "creation": {
        "name": "Firebase Inc",
        "location": "USA"
      },

      "google": {
        "creattion": {
          "name": "Google Inc",
          "location": "USA"
        }
      }

      "facebook": {
      },

      "apple": {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There are tens of thousands of records under `companies` key. How do i efficiently execute following queries?

How do I query only the records for which key `creation` is present under their name?

How do I query only the records that DO NOT have key `creation` present under their name?

I also want to call `.on('child_added')` on the returned result set so that I can process only those specific records later on. Is it possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### EDIT: Simpler way without using an extra parameter

#### Queries

Here are the queries to do this without having to use an extra parameter:

- Find the companies *without* `creation`:

  - `var ref = new Firebase(fbUrl+'/companies').orderByChild("creation").equalTo(null);`
- Find the companies *with* `creation`:

  - `var ref = new Firebase(fbUrl+'/companies').orderByChild("creation").startAt(!null);`
- You would add `".indexOn": "creation"` to the rules.

**Edit 2:** I was curious, so I pushed 11,000 records to `/companies2` (half with `creation` children, half without). I was able to retrieve 5500 matching records in ~4 seconds using the above queries (or one of the variants I've shown below).

**Edit 3:** If you're running these queries frequently, it might be worth it to separate children of `/companies` into two bins based the presence of `creation`. That way, you can read the two segments separately without having to rely on queries.

#### Factory

Here is what the revised factory would look like (I've revised the [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/BfOXgF73s46AWTUHvXh6?p=preview) to match):

```js
app.factory("CompaniesFactory",function($q, fbUrl){
  return function(hasCreation){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var ref = new Firebase(fbUrl+'/companies').orderByChild("creation");
    var query;
    if (hasCreation) {
      query = ref.startAt(!null);
      // or: 
      // query = ref.startAt(true);
    } else {
      query = ref.equalTo(null);
      // or:
      // query = ref.endAt(!null);
      // query = ref.endAt(true);
    }
    query.once("value", function(dataSnapshot){
      deferred.resolve(dataSnapshot.val());
    }, function (error) {
      deferred.reject(error);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
});
```

And yes, it is possible to call `.on('child_added')` on the returned dataSnapshot. See [DataSnapshot.ref()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/ref.html).

---

### Original answer using an extra parameter:

*(Keeping this for reference)*

Another way to do it would be by adding another parameter called `hasCreation` to children of `companies` that have `creation`, and query by that.

#### Data

- The query would then be `var ref = new Firebase(fbUrl+'/companies').orderByChild("hasCreation").equalTo(hasCreation);`

  - If `hasCreation` in the query is `null`, the query will return the companies without a `hasCreation` child.
  - If `hasCreation` in the query is `true`, the query will return the companies with `hasCreation===true`.

```json
{
  "company1" : {
    "creation" : {
      "name" : "company1"
    },
    "hasCreation" : true
  },
  "company2" : {
    "name" : "company2"
  },
  "company3" : {
    "name" : "company3"
  },
  "company4" : {
    "creation" : {
      "name" : "company4"
    },
    "hasCreation" : true
  }
}
```

#### Rules

You would add the `".indexOn" : "hasCreation"` to your rules like so:

```
  "so:29179389":{
    ".read" : true,
    ".write" : true,
    "companies" : {
      ".indexOn" : "hasCreation"
    }
  }
```

#### Companies Factory

```
app.factory("CompaniesFactory",function($q, fbUrl){
  return function(hasCreation){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if (!hasCreation) {
      hasCreation = null;
    }
    var ref = new Firebase(fbUrl+'/companies').orderByChild("hasCreation").equalTo(hasCreation);
    ref.once("value", function(dataSnapshot){
      deferred.resolve(dataSnapshot.val());
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
});
```

#### Controller

```
app.controller('HomeController',function($scope,fbUrl,CompaniesFactory) {
 $scope.getCompanies = function(hasCreation) {
  var companies = new CompaniesFactory(hasCreation).then(function(data){
     console.log(data);
     $scope.companies = data;
   });
 }
});
```

#### HTML

```
<body ng-app="sampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="HomeController">
    <button ng-click="getCompanies(true)">Find with creation</button>
    <button ng-click="getCompanies(false)">Find without creation</button>
    <h2>Companies:</h2>
    {{companies}}
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @kato/@frank, if you see this, are any of the variants from my last edit preferred as best practice? `!null` doesn't really make sense, but it works the same as `true`. Would `.endAt` have an advantage over `.equalTo`?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, is I would set a condition to verify if your xxx.firebaseio.com/Application/companies/______/creation exists. In a empty blank, you can set for loop to irritate over the array of companies.Then, you can create two arrays with angular.forEach: one including those companies which do have 'creation', and the other array in which the elements do not include the 'creation'.

Hope that helps :)

Edit: 
There is another approach to this question, in this thread: 
[Angularfire: how to query the values of a specific key in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014556/angularfire-how-to-query-the-values-of-a-specific-key-in-an-array)

Comment: The problem with this approach, that I'm also facing is, that my companies array is very large. Iterating over tens of thousands of records to get lets say only five records that have `creation` key in them brings my application to  a halt.

Comment: I added the information of data set being large in the questions.